# How to find the sum upto n terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider the series:

$$S(n) = \sin(\pi/3) + (1/2)\sin(2\pi /3) + (1/3)\sin(3\pi/3) +\cdots+ (1/n)\sin(n \pi/3)$$

How to find the sum and generalize it? I tried taking out $√3 /2$ as a common factor, but I failed.

Comment: Are you asking for a closed-form formula?  Why do you think there is one?

Comment: @saulspatz because I need to generalize the sum to get an answer for my exercise

Comment: This isn't the best way to use this site.  Tell us what problem you're trying to solve, and what attempts you have made so far.  After all, it's possible you're taking the wrong approach, isn't it?

Comment: @saulspatz Please help me I tried to take √3/2 common out of it

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Describe your work in the question, not the comments.  What happened when you tried to take a common factor out?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you failed?  Why can't you take out a factor of $\sqrt 3/2?$  That seems perfectly reasonable to me.  What goes wrong?

Comment: Is it the periodicity that's bothering you?  You just need to worry about the remainder of $n$ on division by $6$.  For example $\sin(\frac{6k+3}{3}\pi)=0,$ for all values of $k$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for the info brother. But according to you there can be no generalized form right??

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by a "general form."  You can certainly simplify the expression, but I doubt you'll come up with a compact formula for the sum of $n$ terms.  If you want to compute the infinite sum, that's another matter.  You ought to add to your question a description of what happened when you tried to take ought a common factor.  How far did you get?  What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the sine function is periodic with period $2\pi$ the value of $\sin \frac{2\pi n}{3}$ depends only on the residue class of $n$ modulo $6$.  That is,$$  \sin \frac{2\pi n}{3}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, &n \equiv 1,2 \pmod{6} \\
\frac{-\sqrt 3}{2}, &n \equiv 4,5 \pmod{6} \\
0, &n \equiv 0,3 \pmod{6}
\end{cases}
$$ 
That makes the sum equal to 
$$\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\left (\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+...+a_n \right),$$

Where the form of $a_n$ depends on the congruence class of $n.$  I don't see a way to get a compact formula for this.  It's possible to compute the infinite sum, but I don't suppose you're up to that yet.

Comment: You have always been kind to me. Thanks for your help bro. I am grateful. Maybe I always try to experiment with a sum. I am sorry brother